# Rack attack filling up hard drive space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rackattack

I have also asked this on [GitHub](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/issues/461) but it seems nobody is answering.

The problem is I am using Rack Attack as a gem for blocking scraping.

My config is located [here](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/docs/example_configuration.md)

The problem I am running into is it is writing cache to the file system and filling up resulting in the following error

```
No space left on device@ rb_sysopen - /var/app/current/tmp/cache/.rack%3A%3Aattack%3A5249968%3Areq%2Fip%3A104.199.176.25320191129-1869-11sg00n
```

How do i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The gem documentation doesn't provide any information about the caching mechanism, but looking in the source code tells that [they're using the `Rails.cache`](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/blob/master/lib/rack/attack/cache.rb#L10) so you can look at that.

Based on the error you gave, your Rails application seem to use the `:file_store` cache (it's the default one), and [the Rails documentation says](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-filestore):

> As the cache will grow until the disk is full, it is recommended to periodically clear out old entries.

But I found [a `cleanup` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb#L43) which is present since a while (I checked from Rails version 3 to 6) and seem to know about expired data, but there were [a bug preventing Rails to clean expired data](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30788) that has been fixed in Rails 5.2. If you're using Rails 5.2 and newer try to set an expiration time to the cache:

```rb
config.cache_store = :file_store, Rails.root.join('tmp', 'cache'), { expires_in: 10.minutes }
```

*Please update the cache path (second argument) and the adapt the `expires_in` value for your case.*

Another option would be to [change the Rails cache store](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores) to something like [Redis](http://redis.io) (using the [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) gem) or [Memcached](https://memcached.org).

Redis will delete the expired keys and Memcached delete the oldest keys when reaching the limit of allowed space.